# Documenting big models in postman

Tags: api, postman

I'm building a postman documentation for a big model that has lots of parameters. Instead of having to copy the same model in different APIs and examples, is there a way to create a single model and refer to it in different APIs?

Comment: I only see document for overall API request, I don't see document for parameter. Can you guide me what you do?

Comment: @DoNhuVy So let's say I have a model called "Employee" that is used in 4 APIs; each having 3 examples (1 success and 2 failures). If the employee model has 8 fields, I'll need to copy it in all apis and examples. If at any point in time I add, modify or remove a field I'll need to reflect the change everywhere the model exists. Ideally, I'd like a central location where I create the model in postman and have it used by the different APis.